# Swift 1.2 , same instance methods name different parameters do not work anymore

Tags: ios, swift

I follow the Standford course and now Im stuck because same instance methods name with different parameters now give errors

```
func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    if operandStack.count >= 2 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}

func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double) {
    if operandStack.count >= 1 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}
```

The fix I have is rename one function to another name. What should I do ? I am new to Swift so please keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should rename one of those functions. Name the first one performTwoParameterOperation, for example.